# How to get all table name on postgresql with Exception?

Tags: database, postgresql

i am working with codeigniter right now, i want get all name of tables in database postgres. So i am using `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public';`

it shown all table name, but i want one table in exception, not shown. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'nameOfTableYouWantToExcept';
```

this will retrieve all the table name **except** the one you `!=` on `table_name`.

Comment: it says :ERROR: column " " does not exist